# Unity New Input System - What Is The Correct Way To Check If Any Button From An Action Map Was Pressed?

Tags: unity, input

Good Morning All,

I am using Unity's New Input System. I have an Action Map created called 'Menu'.

Currently, this is how I check for ***specific*** button presses.

```
If( xxx.Menu.Select.WasPressedThisFrame() )
{
  // Do Stuff
}
```

The above works fine. However, now I need to check if ***any*** button was pressed from the Action Map.

For example, my game could show an image of a PS4's X Button. I need to detect if the player presses the right ***or wrong*** button. If the right button is pressed they win and if the wrong button is pressed they lose.

Hopefully this makes it even more clear:

```
If( METHOD THAT CHECKS IF ANY INPUT FROM THE MENU ACTION MAP WAS PRESSED ) // <- This is what I need
{
      If( xxx.Menu.Select.WasPressedThisFrame() )
      {
        // You win!
      }

      Else
      {
        // You Lose!
      }
}
```

To summarize, I'm looking for a method from Unity's New Input System that checks if any button was pressed. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: How big is the set of buttons? All keyboard keys or are we talking about a small subset of them or a controller? An action map seems the wrong way, since you do not want to bind actions in this case. But the new input system still allows you to read the values: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.7/manual/Workflow-Direct.html

Comment: Thanks for the response @Zibelas! I'm a bit confused with why you think an Action Map seems wrong. The reason that I use an Action Map is so that the player can use whatever controller they prefer. So whether they use a PS4 Controller and hit 'X' or press the space bar on their keyboard, both can be mapped to 'Select'. That being said, I don't think the provided documentation solves my issue unfortunately.

Comment: Because an action map represents a direct action. Press X to jump, press square to fire, not that you are checking in the jump method call if you press the fire square.

Comment: Good to hear! Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a setup like this :
[image]

And then check with:

```cs
if (inputActions.actionMap.TestAction.WasPressedThisFrame())
{
    if (inputActions.actionMap.Good.WasPressedThisFrame())
    {
        Debug.Log("You win!");
    }
    else if (inputActions.actionMap.Bad.WasPressedThisFrame())
    {
        Debug.Log("You lose!");
    }
}
```

But, in general, with the new Input System it might make more sense to organize the input logic by using callbacks, rather than polling. Like this:

```cs
inputActions.actionMap.Good.performed += () =>
{
    Debug.Log("You win!");
}
inputActions.actionMap.Bad.performed += () =>
{
    Debug.Log("You lose!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @PepeOjeda! The first half of your answer is honestly a great idea. I will probably end up using it if there is no method that looks for /any/ input. Though, I'd be pretty surprised and disappointed if the New Input System doesn't have a method to do that. As for the second half, using callbacks is not very convenient in my game. The good/bad buttons change too frequently based on mini-games.

Comment: That's fair enough. You can rebind the actions at runtime through code, though, so maybe that's something worth looking into?

Comment: Just closing the loop to let you know I ended up using your solution. Having a specific Action for "Any" button being pressed seemed to work fine and is the best solution I've seen. Thanks again, @PepeOjeda. Really great solution! I'll probably make a separate thread inquiring about rebinding actions at runtime like you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how you can check for any `InputAction` being triggered in any or specific `InputActionMap`:

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class TestAnyButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InputActionAsset iaa;

    void Start()
    {
        iaa.Enable();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (iaa.Any((ia) => ia.WasPressedThisFrame()))
        {
            Debug.Log("Any action", this);
        }


        if (iaa.FindActionMap("AcitonMapName").Any((ia) => ia.WasPressedThisFrame()))
        {
            Debug.Log("Any action in an action map", this);
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative way is to subscribe to all the `InputAction`s in a map:

```
public class TestAnyButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InputActionAsset iaa;

    private InputActionMap observedMap;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        iaa.Enable();

        observedMap = iaa.FindActionMap("ActionMapName");
        foreach (var inputAction in observedMap)
        {
            inputAction.started += OnStarted;
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        foreach (var inputAction in observedMap)
        {
            inputAction.started -= OnStarted;
        }
    }

    void OnStarted(CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.started)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{context.action.name} started.", this);
        }
    }
}
```